# Button to change image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make that when pressed left or right button shows up this image images/2header-pic.jpg with jquery.

I tried some code from here that I found, but nothing works. My code is:

Edit: Added some more css and html code maybe it doesn`t work because of my other code.

HTML

```
 <div id="header-info">
            <div class="header-info-text1">
                <div class="image-info-header">
                <span id="infoimg-left"><button id="infoimg-left-button"><i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-2x" class="infoimg-left"></i></button></span>
                <img src="images/headerinfoimg.jpg" id="infoimg-id" class="infoimg">
                <span id="infoimg-right"><i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-2x" class="infoimg-right"></i></span>
                </div>
                <p>
 TEXT
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#header-info {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fffffe;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #ff8906;
}

.header-info-text1 {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: #ff8906;
    width: 100%;

}

.header-info-text1 p {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

.infoimg {
    float: right;
    width: calc(50%);
    margin: -20px calc(5%);
    
}

#infoimg-left {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(48%);
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 80px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fffffe;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: This is a very vague question, what Javascript have you already tried? In which element are you trying to place the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with JQuery iusing the [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method to handle click events.

The image is changed by updating the `"src"` attribute. Note that you need to add some random number otherwise the image won't change because the browser will use the one cached.

Here's a demo.

```js
$("#infoimg-left").click(function() {
  console.log("Handler for .click() called.");
  var src = "https://picsum.photos/200" + "?" + Math.random();
  console.log("new image:", src);
  $("#infoimg-id").attr("src", src);
});
```

```css
#infoimg-left {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(48%);
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffffe;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-info-header">
  <span id="infoimg-left"><button id="infoimg-left-button"><i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-2x" class="infoimg-left"></i></button></span>
  <img src="images/headerinfoimg.jpg" id="infoimg-id" class="infoimg">
  <span id="infoimg-right"><i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-2x" class="infoimg-right"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: nothing happens when i press the button :)

Comment: I attached the event handler to the buttons container. Now it should work. You can remove the `<button>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create array of path to images:

```js
    
    // create array of images urls 
    const images = [
      'https://cdn.britannica.com/67/19367-050-885866B4/Valley-Taurus-Mountains-Turkey.jpg',
      'https://cdn.unenvironment.org/2022-09/nicolai-kramer-unsplash.jpg',
      'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/idyllic-summer-landscape-clear-mountain-lake-alps-45054687.jpg'
    ]
    
    // create index number
    let idxImg = 0;
    
    // define img element
    const imgNode = document.querySelector('img');
    
    // set default images
    imgNode.src = images[idxImg];
    
    // listen click on button
    const btn = document.getElementById('next');
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      idxImg++;
      idxImg = idxImg >= images.length ? 0 : idxImg;
      imgNode.src = images[idxImg];
    })
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="">
<div>
  <button id='next'>NEXT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn`t work ;d

Comment: @Nemmem It is okay. Just wait 1-2 second for loading image.